# why this code ignores the entry if try to add more than one, in the linked list program?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I dont understand what is wrong with this code i mean it ran but not allowing to add more than one value in the list and if i tried to add more than one value it just ignores that entry

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<limits>//For cleaning buffer i used some code in the line 19
#include<ios>//For cleaning buffer i used some code in the line 19
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    node *link;
    int info1;
    string info2;
};
node *START=NULL;
node *createNode(){
    node *obj=new node();
    obj->link=NULL;
    cout<<"Enter the integer info 1"<<endl;
    cin>>obj->info1;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    cout<<"Enter the String info 2"<<endl;
    getline(cin,obj->info2);
    return obj;
}
```

I double checked this add() function but i didnt found out the problem

```
void add(){//Addition from last
    if(START==NULL){
        START=createNode();
    }
    else{
        node *temp=START;
        while(temp!=NULL){//Main Logic
            temp=temp->link;
        }
        temp=createNode();
    }
}
```

I double checked this del() function too!! but i didnt found out the problem

```
void del(){//Deletion from beginning
    if(START==NULL) 
        cout<<endl<<"There is nothing to delete!!"<<endl;
    else{
        node *temp=START;
        START=START->link;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

I double checked this print() function too!! but i didnt found out the problem

```
void print(){
    if(START==NULL)
        cout<<endl<<"There is nothing to print!!"<<endl;
    else{
        node *temp=START;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            cout<<"Info 1 : "<<temp->info1<<endl;
            cout<<"Info 2 : "<<temp->info2<<endl<<endl;
            temp=temp->link;
        }
    }
}
int menu(){
    int choice;
    cout<<endl<<"1. Add"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Delete"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Print"<<endl;
    cout<<"0. Exit"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return choice;
}
int main(){
    int choice;
    cout<<"Hello There!!"<<endl<<"Choose one option!!"<<endl;
    do{
        choice=menu();
        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                add();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                del();
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                print();
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(choice!=0);
}
```

My conclusion is that there something wrong with the add() function but i am unable to find what is!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please peruse our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have posted more code than is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` function is flawed. When you attempt to add the second node, you create a new node, store its address in `temp`, and then leave the function. The variable `temp` passes out of scope, and the new node is lost. It is never appended to the list. You must rethink that function.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually linked the `temp` node you create to the previous node. You create a node, through `temp=createNode()`. However, no previous node links to this new node.

Hence, you have to change the condition `(temp!=NULL)` to `(temp->link != NULL)`. As soon as you detect that the link to a new node is `NULL`, you create your new node and assign it to `temp->link`. This will link the last node in the linked list to the new node you just created.

Hence, your new code would have the following structure:

```
//Addition to last element of linked list
void add(){
    if(START==NULL){
        START=createNode();
    }
    else{
        node *temp = START;
        while(temp->link != NULL){ // CHANGE HERE
            temp = temp->link; 
        }
        temp->link = createNode(); // CHANGE HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , your code worked for me but i still don't understand why my add() is wrong, can you please elaborate my mistake ? ,i will really appreciate if you will .

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approach based on pointing at the link you may want to attach the new node to. This eliminates the need for a special case for `START` since `START` is merely another `link` with a different name.

By pointing at the `link` we have both the insertion point in the previous node *and* a pathway to the next node in the list. This reduces the need for extra book-keeping.

```cpp
void add() { 
    node **curpp = &START; // point at the start pointer
    while ((*curpp) != NULL) { // test if the pointer at the current pointer is in use
        curpp = &(*curpp )->link; // in use, advance to next link
    }
    *curpp = createNode(); // create and store new pointer at the current pointer
}
```

Side note: by making all of the functions depend on `START`, a global variable, you can only ever have one linked list. This isn't particularly useful. You should either pass in the list's root node to functions that need it or make a linked list class that manages its own root node (and thus its own list)

Comment: thanks for checking out my code and making it small and helping me in making it more efficient , i truly appreciate your effort